# Autopy screen capture on OSX

Tags: python, macos, screen-capture, autopy

I'm using Autopy on osx 10.7.4 and everything in the module works except for the capture_screen method.  Whenever I use it to capture the screen the image it saves is just completely black. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2):

Known bug: https://github.com/msanders/autopy/issues/32

Instead of autopy, you can just use the `screencapture` OS X utility through `os.system`:

```
os.system("screencapture foo.png")
```